# Is there a way to prevent Play from auto-reloading?

Tags: scala, playframework

While working on some projects, I would sometimes prefer to disable by the auto-reloading feature of Play (and only reload manually).

Is there a way to quickly achieve this? (Other than typing `start` at the play prompt, which adds some overhead as it packages the app.)

Comment: But how would you reload manually other than stopping dev mode and manually compiling (and restarting)?

Comment: By typing Ctrl+D, and `run` again.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Scala app that will start the Play app:

```
import play.api.{Application, ApplicationLoader, Environment, Mode, Play}
import play.core.server.{ServerConfig, ServerProvider}

object MyPlayApp extends App {

  val config = ServerConfig(mode = Mode.Dev)

  val application: Application = {
    val environment = Environment(config.rootDir, this.getClass.getClassLoader, Mode.Dev)
    val context = ApplicationLoader.createContext(environment)
    val loader = ApplicationLoader(context)
    loader.load(context)
  }

  Play.start(application)

  val serverProvider: ServerProvider = ServerProvider.fromConfiguration(this.getClass.getClassLoader, config.configuration)
  serverProvider.createServer(config, application)

}
```

Then run it: `sbt "runMain MyPlayApp"`